# Two generic types have direct connection, how to avoid repeated input?

Tags: c#, generics

```
public interface IService<T> where  T : IComparable<T> { }
public class CommonController<S, T> where S : IService<T>, new() where T : IComparable<T> { }

public class CustomerService : IService<int> { }

// Correct
public class CustomerController : CommonController<CustomerService, int> { }

// Confict, from CustomerService, T is int, but the second type is long
public class CustomerController : CommonController<CustomerService, long> { }
```

it's obvious to guess the second type 'int' from CustomerService. Is possible to remove the second generic type and how?

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: Can you please replace the pseudo-code with real code?

Comment: And please add the rest of the class/interface definitions.

Comment: I added the full title codes, hope they are clear for you. Thanks.

Comment: I fixed your code. It now compiles - except for the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can eliminate the repetitiveness of the `T` by doing this:

```
public static class Foo<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public interface IService { }
    public class CommonController<S> where S : IService, new() { }
    public class CustomerService : IService { }
    public class CustomerController : CommonController<CustomerService> { }
}
```

But if you need to define `CustomerService` and `CustomerController` outside of `Foo<T>` then you basically get back to square one.

```
public static class Foo<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public interface IService { }
    public class CommonController<S> where S : IService, new() { }
}

public class CustomerService : Foo<int>.IService { }

public class CustomerController : Foo<int>.CommonController<CustomerService> { }
```

So the answer, is, basically, no.

Comment: Inspired by your idea, I have added more simplicity to the codes. Thanks.